# Finding the value of k in a matrix

Tags: matrices, algebra-precalculus

I can't figure out how to solve this question:
Find the value(s) of $k$ such that
$$A=\begin{bmatrix}  3 &0 &3 \\  -6 &3 &3k \\ -3 &6 &3k^2 \end{bmatrix}$$
has an inverse. 
Any help would be greatly appreciated, I've been working on it for a long time!

Comment: What is the determinant of $A$?

Answer (score 1):

A matrix only has an inverse iff its determinant is non-zero.

$A=3\begin{bmatrix}  1 &0 &1 \\  -2 &1 &k \\ -1 &2 &k^2 \end{bmatrix}$

and the determinant is then $27(k^2-2k-3)=27(k-3)(k+1)$, and so $k$ can take any value other than $3$ and $-1$.